# jQuery: function gets triggered multiple times

Tags: jquery, load, each

I have below function which executes the qtip2 tooltip on certain divs ( #block_profile ) the problem is that it gets triggered multiple times. So If I click a 4th #block_profile it calls this function 4 times. How Can I make it only execute for the exact div that has been clicked?

```
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Make sure to only match links to wikipedia with a rel tag
    $('div.block_profile[rel]').each(function () {


        // We make use of the .each() loop to gain access to each element via the "this" keyword...
        $(this).qtip(
            {
                content:{
                    // Set the text to an image HTML string with the correct src URL to the loading image you want to use
                    text:'<img src="/assets/ux/modal/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
                    ajax:{
                        url:'/profiles/get_info/' + $(this).attr('rel') // Use the rel attribute of each element for the url to load
                    },
                    title:{
                        button:false
                    }
                },
                position:{
                    my:'top left',
                    target: 'mouse',
                    viewport:$(window), // Keep the tooltip on-screen at all times
                    adjust:{
                        x:10, y:10
                    }
                },
                hide:{
                    fixed:false // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
                },
                style:{
                    classes:'container ui-tooltip ui-tooltip-tip'
                }
            })
    })

        // Make sure it doesn't follow the link when we click it
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

the html:

```
<div id ="block_profile" class ="block_profile rel="1">div 1</div>
<div id ="block_profile" class ="block_profile rel="2">div 2</div>
<div id ="block_profile" class ="block_profile rel="3">div 3</div>
<div id ="block_profile" class ="block_profile rel="4">div 4</div>
<div id ="block_profile" class ="block_profile rel="5">div 5</div>
```

Comment: Element IDs in html must be **unique**. Fix those.

Comment: Do you notice that in your `class` you're missing a double quote?

Comment: Apart from the malformed html, your code [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dcnSs/). What do you mean with "click" and "function" fires multiple times? You don't have any click function there besides the `event.preventDefault()`. The hover's qtip is working fine, I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Make sure to only match links to wikipedia with a rel tag
    $('div.block_profile[rel]')
        .qtip({
            ...
        })
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

The `each` call isn't necessary. Check out [this demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/basic) for example.

Comment: Yes but this does not work. Perhaps Its other code interfering I have lots of query functions and plugins in my app. I thought My code was bad but I have to validate this to be really sure. thx

Comment: If this doesn't work, something else must be wrong. The `each` call really shouldn't be there. I suggest you take a look at the other comments for hints on cleaning up your html.

Comment: Thx I plan a cleanup its indeed not the neatest html your code is correct and should work indeed its a failure on my part in the html